# Open a website in Internet Explorer from command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

How do I open up a website in Internet Explorer, launching it from the command line in Windows 7?

This is the webpage I want to have open through IE:

`http://example.com/api/sendValidSMSdataUrl.php?login=demodlc&pword=YourPassword&msg=msg&senderid=OPTINS&mobnum=mobnum`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099153/open-tabs-in-internet-explorer-with-cmd/45808976#45808976

Answer (score 14):

## Open with Internet Explorer

The following command will open a new Internet Explorer window (the 32-bit or 64-bit version depending on the system, assuming it's installed), and load the page:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://onlinesms.in/api/sendValidSMSdataUrl.php?login=demodlc&pword=YourPassword&msg=msg&senderid=OPTINS&mobnum=mobnum"
```

## Open with the default browser

If you just want to load the default browser (which might not be Internet Explorer), you can use the following instead:

```
start "link" "http://onlinesms.in/api/sendValidSMSdataUrl.php?login=demodlc&pword=YourPassword&msg=msg&senderid=OPTINS&mobnum=mobnum"
```

Quotes are required to avoid parsing errors due to reserved characters, which would need to be escaped separately otherwise.

The advantage is that the if the default browser is open already, the page should be loaded in a new tab, rather then a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `START "title" "http://..."`, it will use the default browser though (not IE, which might not even be installed)

Comment: That won't work as-is because `&` is a reserved character, and should be escaped. An easier solution is to just enclose the URL in straight quotes, and add an extra title string parameter before the actual link (as per the `start` command syntax).